# Why is this range based query so much quicker

Tags: sql, optimization, range

At work we had a query on a table that had the following structure:

```
ip_from(number), ip_to(number), country, city, state, isp, latitude, longitude.
```

This table had approx 6.1 million rows.

To find out the details for a given IP address we used a query like the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Ip2location
WHERE
  :ip_num BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to;
```

On Oracle 10 in our dev database this took approximately 17 seconds to return a row, depending on the `ip_num` passed in. On our beefier live system it took maybe 5-6 seconds, which was still too slow to do in real time and we needed to select this via a background job.

**Not** ideal, especially as our real time systems really needed the ip details.

The type of index used was a standard BTREE index spanning both `ip_from` and `ip_to`. We looked into a lot of things to try to speed this up such as [range partitioning](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Range_partitioning). We didn't apply that in the end as it requires Oracle Enterprise. We also looked at increasing the concurrency of the table but that had no noticeable effect.

Anyway when having my morning coffee I realised that I thought there could be a performance enhancement by running the following query: (This is from memory, there may be a couple of mistakes. Also we selected individual fields not everything)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ip2location
WHERE 
  ip_from = (
    SELECT max(ip_from)
      FROM ip2location
      WHERE ip_from <= :ip_num
  )
AND
  ip_to >= ip_num;
```

This works for our data set because there's no overlapping ranges between `ip_from` and `ip_to`.

However what I wasn't prepared for is how much faster the second query is. The time on our dev database was reduced from 17 seconds to 0.007 seconds.

This makes little sense to me. I'd expect some performance increase, but not that much. Shouldn't the database statistics have figured out there is no overlap and optimised accordingly? Also there has to be a recognised quicker way to select using ranges?

My question is: why is the second query so much faster even using a sub-select?

Comment: Have you tried separate indexes instead of a combined one?

Comment: Will not the explain command tell you why?

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy we did for the old version of the query. A combined index was faster. We intend to test with the single index against the new query.
@nate c - I didn't find much useful in the explain plan. I'm a developer not a DBA. Would it be useful if at work I put in both the explain plans into the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the performance increase is obvious. Its because there is an index on ip_from , so max(ip_from) can be obtained in constant time because as you know indexing sorts out the values. the range is also easily computed because of binary search over the btree.

while in the previous query has to do a table scan all over the data to compute the range bounds

Comment: Is that true even though there was a combined index?

Comment: Wes: The DB engine doesn't know that `ip_to` is never less than `ip_from`.

Comment: @Gabe Wouldn't the statistic engine find this out? I think i'll ask a couple of different questions related to this query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that index statistics are kept only on a per-column basis.